# Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy got error with public interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, castle-dynamicproxy

I have public interface and internal impl,

```
public interface IService
{
    ...
}
internal class Service: IService
{
    ...
}
```

I registered them via

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
       .EnableInterfaceInterceptors()
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
       .AsSelf()
```

But I'm getting error

> The component Activator = Service (ReflectionActivator), Services = [~.IService, ~.Service], 
>   Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.MatchingScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope cannot use interface interception as it provides services that are not publicly visible interfaces. Check your registration of the component to ensure you're not enabling interception and registering it as an internal/private interface type.

Why am I getting this error? My interface is public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `AsSelf()` method, the container will add the concrete type in the service list of the current registration.

The error message is

> cannot use interface interception as it provides services that are not publicly visible **interface**

It means that all services of the registration should be an interface which is not the case. You can see it in the [EnsureInterfaceInterceptionApplies method](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy/blob/develop/src/Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy/RegistrationExtensions.cs)

```
private static void EnsureInterfaceInterceptionApplies(IComponentRegistration componentRegistration)
{
    if (componentRegistration.Services
        .OfType<IServiceWithType>()
        .Select(s => new Tuple<Type, TypeInfo>(s.ServiceType, s.ServiceType.GetTypeInfo()))
        .Any(s => !s.Item2.IsInterface || !ProxyUtil.IsAccessible(s.Item1)))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            string.Format(
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                RegistrationExtensionsResources.InterfaceProxyingOnlySupportsInterfaceServices,
                componentRegistration));
    }
}
```

If you remove the `.AsSelf()` call, the code will work.

Comment: Thank you, but i keep getting this error even when both interface and impl are public.I'm confused with that.

Comment: @Horosho I could reproduce it with public interface too. If you remove the `AsSelf()` call is it working ?

Comment: The error message is *is not publicly visible interface* which can be translated as *public **AND** interface*

Comment: Yes, it works without AsSelf(), now i catch my fault.